# Laravel: two forms in one page validation error

Tags: php, laravel

I create 2 forms in one page using laravel but when I submit the first one it shows the error of the second form. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the form id if you use AJAX

If Not

The rule:- `<form>` tag only have one button for submitting the form

Try This

```
<button id="register" type="submit">Register</button>

$('#register').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
});
```

Comment: i have two forms and each form has his own button !

Comment: the other button who should be disabled non ?

Comment: when the request completed then your button is enabled automatically if you are not using ajax

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example maybe makes you understand and apply the logic,

View:

```
   <form action="/link" method="post">
        <input name="name" value="1">

        <button type="submit" name="form1">Submit 1</button>
   </form>

    <form action="/link" method="post">
        <input name="name" value="1">

        <button type="submit" name="form2">Submit 2</button>
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
if ($request->has('form1') {
    return 'form1';
}

if ($request->has('form2') {
    return 'form2';
}
```